# Postfixadmin on Debain 10 | Cant install php5-imap

Tags: php, linux, debian, postfix-mta, legacy

I'm currently working on a private mailserver for **Debian 10**. Everything works so far but **postfixadmin** gives me headcaches.

Theres a problem with the setup it says:

"Warning: Depends on: IMAP functions - NOT FOUND
To install IMAP support, install php5-imap
Without IMAP support, you won't be able to create subfolders when creating mailboxes."

The problem here is that **you cannot install the php5 version of php5-imap** whatsoever.

I tried to install the php7-version of it but the setup.php wont recognize it.

Now to my question: Is there a way to install the php5-imap package?

If that isnt working: Is there a way to "trick" the setup.php, that it will recognize the php7-imap?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php5.6-imap` can be installed on debian 10 from [Sury repository](https://deb.sury.org/):

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
curl https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php5.6-imap
```